# call stored procedure with parameter webapi

Tags: stored-procedures, webapi

I have created this stored procedure with a parameter which is working fine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSponsoringWithParameters]
@sponsoroption nvarchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * from sponsoring where dbo.sponsoroption.sponsoroptionID= @sponsoroption
```

Then I created this Webapi which should also be fine:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<VewSponsoring[]> GetSponsoring(string parm1)
    {
        VewSponsoring[] u;
        u = _context.VewSponsoring
     .FromSqlRaw("execute spSponsoringWithParameters {0}", parm1)
        .ToArray();
        return u;}
```

When I start the local server: how can I approach the stored procedure with a parameter:
It works without a parameter

https://localhost:44365/api/sponsoringtest

, but I do not know how to this with a parameter??

Answer (score 0):

String is a simple type so you'll be passing the parameters via the querystring as that is where Web API will look by default:

https://localhost:44365/api/sponsoringtest?parm1=VAL

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) on Web API parameter binding.